# Rename a file in Roaming folder for each user in a computer using powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, rename, user-profile, appdata

I am trying to rename a file in \appdata\Roaming\ for each user profile on a pc.
The command I am trying this, but not working.
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
$old = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\test.txt'
$rename = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\test-old.txt'
Get-ChildItem $rename | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $old -NewName $_ -Force}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What am I doing wrong? Almost everything ;-).

Please take a look if this does what you need:

```
$folders = get-childitem 'C:\users\' -directory

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $file = Join-Path $folder -ChildPath 'AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\test.txt'
    if (Test-Path $file) {
        rename-item $file -NewName 'test-old.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I ran that as it is, it ran without showing any errors, but didn't change the file name.
Any advise?

Comment: Any advise please?

Comment: I changed C:\users*\ to C:\users\ as I assumed that the folders are in subfolders - is my assumption correct or not?

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so much. 
Below worked. Just put \\*\ after C:\users

$folders = get-childitem 'C:\users\*\' -directory

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $file = Join-Path $folder -ChildPath 'AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\test.txt'
    if (Test-Path $file) {
        rename-item $file -NewName 'test-old.txt'
    }
}

Comment: Hey @Farbkeis, 
how can I skip file copy if the same file exists already?
my current code to copy the file is this - 
$Source = '\\ggfglenser04\h\AppsData\SAPUILandscape.xml'
$Destination = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69716214/skip-file-copy-if-target-exist-powershell