# Skip file copy if target exist - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy, skip

Can you please help? I have the below PowerShell code to copy a file (test.txt) into each user's roaming folder. It works. but I want to skip copying the file if `test-old.txt` (this is previously re-named file) exists already. Thank you for your help in advance.

fyi - I am happy to have a new code altogether if that works.

```
$Source = '\\ser04\h\AppsData\test.txt'

$Destination = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\'

Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the path for `test-old.txt` would be each user's `..\SAP\Common\` folder you would only need to add an `if` condition to your existing code to check if the file exists on said folder. A simple way to do this is with [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.1).

Remember to add `-Force` switch to `Get-ChildItem` if you want to target `Default` and `Default User` folders.

```
$Source = '\\ser04\h\AppsData\test.xml'
$Destination = 'C:\users\*\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common\'

Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {
    
    $testOld = Join-Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'test-old.txt'

    if(-not(Test-Path $testOld))
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I ran it but it won't copy the file if the file doesn't exist.
What am I missing in this code?

Comment: @RIC try using the updated code

Comment: That work @Santiago, you are a lifesaver. thank you so much, mate.
Could you do me a favor? please replace the server name with something else for me.

Comment: You are a gentleman. Thanks, mate.